# Finding SQLite Server

Tags: sqlite, server

I am trying to pull data from our SQLite server, but I don't know the name of the server. Is there a way to use the command line or PowerShell to find the name of it so I can pull data out?

The person that developed the database was abruptly let go and I am learning this on the fly. Thank you for the help!

Comment: SQLite is serverless - it is likely a file within the project.

Comment: Ok, I'll check that. I know this is like sqlite101, but this got dropped on me and has to get done today.

Comment: You mean SQL server maybe. Try to get some source code if you have in-house applications using that server, or use a port scanner in your LAN (for SQL Server you should be looking for machines that have port 1433 open). But first of all you have to know what to look for.